# How to do an exact query search in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've made a script that searches by given filters. Everything works fine, except **male / female** search because the word **female** contains the word **male** in it.
Selecting male gives me female results as well.

I've tried adding '\b' and '\s' before and after the gender selection in JS, both with single and double slashes.
Here is the code below:

```
<div id="filters">
    <h2>Filter Tables By</h2>
    Topic:
    <select id="topic_group" onchange="createSearchString();">
        <option></option>
        <option>Cancer</option>
        <option>Smoking</option>
        <option>Vaccinations</option>
        <option>Health Screenings</option>
        <option>Usual Place of Health  Care</option>
    </select>
    Population of interest (Total, Male, Female):
    <select id="popinterest_group" onchange="createSearchString();">
        <option></option>
        <option>Total</option>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="/TemplatePackage/3.0/js/libs/jquery-datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            sDom:'<"nhis_search"f>t<"nhis_length"l> <"nhis_pagination"ip>',
            aaSorting: [],
            oLanguage: { sSearch: 'Additional search terms:' },
        });
    });

    var searchString = new String();

    function createSearchString() {
        searchString = $('#topic_group').val() + ' ' + $('#popinterest_group').val() + ' ' + $('#outcomes_group').val();
        $('#example_filter').find('input').val(searchString);
        $('#example_filter').find('input').trigger('keyup');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can check dataTable forum [https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/49603](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/49603) they posted an answer

Comment: why don't you add value in your select option? use boolean value 0 as male, 1 as female, and then when you select one of them, get the value and then filter with condition if 0 return gender == "male" and otherwise

Comment: use regex to match exact word /^male$/g for male and /^female$/g for female

Answer (score 1):

Just add value in your filter option and then check the **selected** option when **onchange**, then use datatable filter to filter data based on **column** and **filter**

Note: Don't use **search()** method if your purpose is to filter data by using exact value

```
<div id="filters">
    <h2>Filter Tables By</h2>
    Topic:
    <select id="topic_group" onchange="createSearchString();">
        <option></option>
        <option>Cancer</option>
        <option>Smoking</option>
        <option>Vaccinations</option>
        <option>Health Screenings</option>
        <option>Usual Place of Health  Care</option>
    </select>
    Population of interest (Total, Male, Female):
    <select id="popinterest_group" onchange="createSearchString();">
        <option></option>
        <option>Total</option>
        <option value="0">Male</option>
        <option value="1">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script src="/TemplatePackage/3.0/js/libs/jquery-datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').dataTable({
            sDom:'<"nhis_search"f>t<"nhis_length"l> <"nhis_pagination"ip>',
            aaSorting: [],
            oLanguage: { sSearch: 'Additional search terms:' },
        });
    });

    function createSearchString() {
        var gender = $('#popinterest_group').children("option:selected").val(); // get the option value
        var filteredData = table
           .column( 0 ) // index of column
           .data()
           .filter( function ( value, index ) {
               if (gender == 0) return value == "male"
               else if (gender == 1) return value == "female"
               return value
           } );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use 'male' and 'female' as gender values instead of binary representation you could use regex in the if condition :  gender.match(/^male$/g) for male and else if gender.match(/^female$/g) to match the exact words